# django form is not picking data which is already in database

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

How do I update my form as the

> form.instance.users = request.user

is not working however if I print request.user on terminal it prints the username of the user currently logged in.

Also in this form I want to pick existing data from that user to display in the form to update it.
The save form button return HttpResponse saved successfully but the data is not stored in the database.

### models.py

```
class BasicDetails(models.Model):
GENDERS = (
    ('M', 'Male'),
    ('F', 'Female'),
    ('O', 'Others'),
)
users = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
father_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
mother_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDERS)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

def __str__(self):
    return self.first_name+" "+ self.last_name


class Education(BasicDetails):
current_year = datetime.date.today().year
YEAR_CHOICES = [(r, r) for r in range(2000, datetime.date.today().year+2)]
course_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
university_board_name = models.CharField(
    max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
passing_year = models.IntegerField(
    choices=YEAR_CHOICES, default=current_year, blank=True, null=True)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

### forms.py

```
class BasicDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = BasicDetails
    fields = '__all__'
    exclude = ['users']
```

class EducationForm(forms.ModelForm):

```
class Meta:
    model = Education
    fields = '__all__'
    exclude = ['users']
```

### views.py

```
@login_required
def View(request):
    education = EducationForm()
    education.instance.users = request.user

    if request.method =="POST":
        print(request.user.id)
        education = EducationForm(request.POST,instance=request.user)
        if education.is_valid():
            education.save(commit=True)
            return HttpResponse("Saved Successfully")
        else:
            education = EducationForm()
    return render(request, 'app/view.html',{'education':education})
```

Comment: What is the purpose of excluding the user field from the forms?

Comment: i want it to automatically fetch the user